# Copying Global Address List contacts including "External Contacts"

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook, gal

I have a VBA code to get whole Global Address List from Outlook 2013 and place the values `Name` and `E-mail Address` in an Excel sheet.

The problem is it's only returning e-mails/users from my SMTP (I guess).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtPOm.jpg]

In this image, we can see the users from the SMTP as mine covered in black and an external user covered in red. My code:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim appOL As Object
    Dim oGAL As Object
    Dim oContact As Object
    Dim oUser As Object
    Dim arrUsers(1 To 75000, 1 To 2) As String
    Dim UserIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set oGAL = appOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries

    For i = 1 To oGAL.Count
        Set oContact = oGAL.Item(i)
        If oContact.AddressEntryUserType = 0 Then
            Set oUser = oContact.GetExchangeUser
            If Len(oUser.lastname) > 0 Then
                UserIndex = UserIndex + 1
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 1) = oUser.Name
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 2) = oUser.PrimarySMTPAddress
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    appOL.Quit

    If UserIndex > 0 Then
        Range("A2").Resize(UserIndex, UBound(arrUsers, 2)).Value = arrUsers
    End If

    Set appOL = Nothing
    Set oGAL = Nothing
    Set oContact = Nothing
    Set oUser = Nothing
    Erase arrUsers

End Sub
```

So, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868214(v=office.14).aspx), the `oContact.AddressEntryUserType` value should include `olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry` (5) for External Users.

What's in your code is just to list Exchange Users, so it also skips mail-enabled PublicFolders, Distribution Lists, etc.

---

**EDIT**
Found a better way to extract name and email address (if any):
Reference: [Obtain the E-mail Address of a Recipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868695.aspx)

```
Option Explicit

Sub tgr()
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
    Dim appOL As Object
    Dim oGAL As Object
    Dim arrUsers() As String
    Dim UserIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sEmail As String

    Set appOL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If appOL Is Nothing Then Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set oGAL = appOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries
    Debug.Print oGAL.Parent.Name & " has " & oGAL.Count & " entries"
    ReDim arrUsers(1 To oGAL.Count, 1 To 2)
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To oGAL.Count
        With oGAL.Item(i)
            Application.StatusBar = "Processing GAL entry #" & i & " (" & .Name & ")"
            sEmail = "" ' Not all entries has email address
            sEmail = .PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
            If Len(sEmail) = 0 Then Debug.Print "No Email address configured for " & .Name & " (#" & i & ")"
            UserIndex = UserIndex + 1
            arrUsers(UserIndex, 1) = .Name
            arrUsers(UserIndex, 2) = sEmail
        End With
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.StatusBar = False
    appOL.Quit

    If UserIndex > 0 Then
        Range("A2").Resize(UserIndex, UBound(arrUsers, 2)).Value = arrUsers
    End If

    Set appOL = Nothing
    Set oGAL = Nothing
    Erase arrUsers

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. You right. Using "oContact.AddressEntryUserType = 0 or oContact.AddressEntryUserType = 5" it returned the same previous result  + another 7k contacts. Including e-mails out of my domain. But I still see some addresses in the GAL inside the Outlook and they're not being returned in the sheet using that code.